Messages from group telegrams are not deleted
There is one Telegram group and for some reason ReplyKeyboard appeared there. I tried to remove it using ReplyKeyboardRemove, but this action removed the keyboard only for some group members, many of them still have it. Can you please tell me how to remove the keyboard completely?
I tried to remove it with ReplyKeyboardRemove, but this action removed the keyboard only for some group members, many of them still have it

do you need that ReplyKeyboard in any group? or you need it only in private messages?

I have so many doubts. Are you sure that the same bot which sent the ReplyKeyboard is used to send the ReplyKeyboardRemove markup? Have you used the selective property while setting the keyboard?
